# Horizontal Scroll Bar Issue w/ media queries

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, media-queries

I'm playing around with media queries and started developing for a mobile screen. I have the first page relatively how I would like it, but I am getting a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom when I resize my screen to <480px. I haven't tested this on a mobile device yet but I'm assuming the same error will appear.

The site is: http://brad.sebdengroup.com/newOdynSite/index.php

To recreate error open the site, resize window to <480px and vertically scroll to the bottom

Comment: Mobile size looks fine to me in Chrome.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom, does a horizontal scroll bar not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
#main span.bold {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    ...
}
#main span{
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

This combination of CSS rules creates an element that's greater than the width of the page. Width 100% does not include any space used by padding, borders, or margins. For instance, if the page width is 480px, the width of the element will be 20px + 480px + 20px = 520px.

To avoid this, try wrapping the content in an additional tag, so that the width and padding can be applied to separate elements, and tweaking the CSS as needed. For example:

```
<span><strong>What have we done?</strong></span>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this without touching my html so will have to look into it further, but you were spot on with the span width + padding causing it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use overflow-x: hidden; on the <body> to simply hide the scroll bar. However, you'll not be able to easily see the content outside the view port.

For mobile devices you can use media queries to specify style sheets:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">`

Or you can use <meta> elements:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`